# Multiple insert in the same query?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

How can I improve this? This looks horrible.

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO items (player_id, sid, pid, itemtype, count, attributes) VALUES (".$db->lastInsertId().", 101, 1, 2460, 1, '')");
$db->query("INSERT INTO items (player_id, sid, pid, itemtype, count, attributes) VALUES (".$db->lastInsertId().", 102,3,1988,1,'')");
$db->query("INSERT INTO items (player_id, sid, pid, itemtype, count, attributes) VALUES (".$db->lastInsertId().", 103,4,2465,1,'')");
$db->query("INSERT INTO items (player_id, sid, pid, itemtype, count, attributes) VALUES (".$db->lastInsertId().", 104,5,2511,1,'')");
$db->query("INSERT INTO items (player_id, sid, pid, itemtype, count, attributes) VALUES (".$db->lastInsertId().", 105,6,2394,1,'')");
$db->query("INSERT INTO items (player_id, sid, pid, itemtype, count, attributes) VALUES (".$db->lastInsertId().", 106,7,2478,1,'')");
$db->query("INSERT INTO items (player_id, sid, pid, itemtype, count, attributes) VALUES (".$db->lastInsertId().", 107,8,2643,1,'')");
$db->query("INSERT INTO items (player_id, sid, pid, itemtype, count, attributes) VALUES (".$db->lastInsertId().", 108,10,2050,1,'')");
$db->query("INSERT INTO items (player_id, sid, pid, itemtype, count, attributes) VALUES (".$db->lastInsertId().", 109,102,2120,1,'')");
$db->query("INSERT INTO items (player_id, sid, pid, itemtype, count, attributes) VALUES (".$db->lastInsertId().", 110,102,2554,1,'')");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html):

> INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows. To do this, include multiple lists of column values, each enclosed within parentheses and separated by commas. Example

You're also going to use [auto increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) for the `player_id` column for this to work.

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO items (sid, pid, itemtype, count, attributes) 
VALUES (101, 1, 2460, 1, ''),
(102,3,1988,1,''),
(103,4,2465,1,'')");
```